# Is there any why to create java object files with JSon string

Tags: java, json

I want an automator library that take a `json` string and generates `java` files.

**Example**

**Input**
Json = `{name:"max",phone:"416465465",email:"xyx@gmail.com"}`

**Output file**

```
public class object{
    public String name;
    public String  phone;
    public String email;

}
```

Comment: Json Jackson would the option

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Comment: @FahadIshaque No it only do maping from json object to already existing java file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is: [jsonschema2pojo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo). Have a look at the [demo site](http://jsonschema2pojo.org/).

It has a mode to generate POJOs out of JSON Schemas, but also out of "plain" JSON Objects.

Note: does JSON Schema draft v3 only, not v4.

Comment: The link is what i was searching for :) Thanks